# pass a variable to view being it a variable of an array of array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create a controller in codeigniter and inside it, created two array:

```
  $header_data['base_url'] = base_url();

  $templates['header'] = "/application/views/templates/header.php";
  $templates['auth_page'] = "/application/views/templates/auth_page.php";
  $templates['footer'] = "/application/views/templates/footer.php";
```

now i created one unique array that contain the previously array:

```
$page_data['data_header'] = $header_data;
$page_data['templates'] = $templates;
```

and pass it to view:

```
$this->load->view('main.php',$page_data);
```

Now once we are in the view how can I call the variable $base_url since it is inside `header_data` which it is inside `$page_data` array ?

Comment: `$page_data['data_header']['base_url']`?

Answer (score 1):

In the view, you can use [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

```
extract($data_header);

echo $base_url;
```